# Fastest way to insert two chars into GB UTF8 string in the latest Powershell 7.x

Tags: string, utf-8, integer, ascii, powershell-7.0

PowerShell 7.1 I have a 1GB text UTF8 text file that I read into a single string.
I've been looking for an efficient method to find all chars with a value greater than 127 and then insert 2 chars ahead of it as markers.
For example the string has Unicode decimal 12288 embedded throughout it. I need char code 128 and then another char holding the the number of chars (or hex if you think hex is better) in the sequence.

If tried to use a FOR loop ($i=0; $i -lt $text.length; $i++) and then checking  [int]$text[$i] to find the next char that is greater than 127.
I then insert my markers using $left+[char]128+$nonAsciirunlen+$right

if $text was [char]12288+' A '+[char]12288+[char]12288 then then it would be changed to [int] values of
128,1, 12288, 32, 65, 32, 128, 2, 12288, 12288

The issue is that it ran overnight and it only processed the approximately the first 350,000. I need it to process in about 10 minutes, but an hour would be acceptable.

My goal is to mark the char sequences with a marker of 128 and the sequence length.
The issue of speed seems to be that each time I append the left side of the string, the two marker codes, and then the right side of the string everything goes slower. I'm guessing it may be that PowerShell is not releasing memory each time I concatenate the strings together, but that is just a wild guess. I did not look at the memory usage. I have 24GB of RAM.

I have tried converting the string to hex using using -encoding UTF8 and Format-Hex, but even 10MB sections cause memory array exceptions from Format-Hex. This is working on the byte level, but the same concept, just that the number of multiple bytes sequences to skip would be a greater size than skipping the actual number of chars.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

This is the fastest I've been able to get it to process. This will allow another application to process the modified UTF8 text file without crashing on the multi-byte characters.

```
$t = [char]12288 + 'A' + [char]12288 + [char]12288 + [char]12288 + ' BC'
$m = [char]128
$len = 0
$stopwatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $t.length; $i++) {
    if (([int]$t[$i]) -lt 128) { continue; }
    $oi = $i

    while (([int]$t[$i]) -gt 127) { $i++; $len++ }
    $l = $t.Substring(0, $oi)
    $r = $t.Substring($oi)
    $t = $l + $m + [char]$len + $r
    $i = $i + 2 
    $len = 0
} #next $i
write-host $stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
#Display results
clear
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $t.Length; $i++) {
     $d = [int]$t[$i];
      write-host $d ',' -NoNewline 
    }; write-host
```

Comment: Why not simply keep it as UTF-8 and work in that character set?  Load that GB into a database and use the power of the database engine to manipulate the text after that.

Comment: It just seems very odd that this is so slow when I can replace any character in the string in seconds. Too bad RegEx is not able to perform this task. Even if I could simply insert code 128 before any char's value >127 then I would be able to do a work around.

Comment: It's not clear at all what you are trying to do. Why do you need to manipulate a UTF-8 file? Into what? What is your end goal? I suggest looking at "binary insertion"...

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70057239/1147688) was the answer you were looking for.